# Download in Background for iPad Application

Tags: iphone, ipad, download

Is it possible to continue download when we close application.
Suppose we have download button in the app and we press it. Download start but if we want to navigate to another application so that we close application, after we come back to that application then the download should complete or in progress.
Thanks in advance.
**EDIT:**
I want to download data in new tab called "Download" as it is in iTune/App Store.
Please Provide some information.
Thanks.

Comment: Some useful links: http://www.audacious-software.com/2011/01/ios-background-processing-limits/

Comment: @Rakesh, Thanks for your help but this not giving me proper information about what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More info can be found on [Apple developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) on Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background section

Comment: I have already ready this document but what i want is if i press download button on one tab it will add progress of that downloading book in another tab. Hope you get if not please comment i will provide more info. Thanks

Comment: make sure that you don't destroy object that does download when switching views, and use views in tab just to check and show progress or start/cancel download...